# Regex javascript to capture multiple occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text, example:

```
Hello ../aaa.jpg ../bbb.jpg ../sss.gif ../xxx.png End of Text
```

I want to get all text with extension jpg and png.

Expected result:

```
 1. ../aaa 
 2. ../bbb 
 3. ../xxx
```

I try with `.match(/(.*).(jpg|png)/)`, but it seems not working as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `g` flag for this to work on multiple occurrences, and you need to match only words (`\w`), the dot (`\.`) and slash (`\/`) before the dot and the extension:

```js
let re = /([\w\.\/]*)\.(?:jpg|png)/g

console.log(
    'Hello ../aaa.jpg ../bbb.jpg ../sss.gif ../xxx.png End of Text'.match(re)
)
```

Comment: They don't want the extensions.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let regex = /\S+?(?=\.(?:jpg|png))/g

console.log(
    'Hello ../aaa.jpg blah ../a-b-c.jpg ../sss.gif ../&%01-x.png End of Text'.match(regex)
)
```

Where

- `\S+?` matches 1 or more (not greedy) non space character
- `(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead
- `(?: ... )` is a non capture group